# call API with ajax Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have request

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:"jsonp",
        url: "http://localhost:8000/api/admin/announces",       
        headers:{         
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHBWZXIiOiIwLjAuMCIsImV4cCI6NDcyNjM4OTEyMiwibG9jYWxlIjoiIiwibWFzdGVyVmVyIjoiIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiIiLCJwbGF0Zm9ybVZlciI6IiIsInVzZXJJZCI6IiJ9.QIZbmB5_9Xlap_gDhjETfMI6EAmR15yBtIQkWFWJkrg',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        succces: function(data){
            console.log('success',data);                    
        }
    });
});
```

and i having 400 bad request error  net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request). What am I missing ?

Comment: Can you try from your browser. Also check cross origin policy in your server. Server cors should allow your localhost:8000.

Comment: 400 - is something resource not found, check API url and method type bcoz rest looks good in you jquery ajax

Comment: Check the server why it rejects your request with status 400.

Comment: You can check for url is working or not, by direct hit on browser, or check for method get or post , and also try dataType:'json'

Comment: my API check on POSTMAN is ok , but browser not ok . i think is token . my code backend send request have token ? so , what am i missing in Ajax

Comment: Try adding extra / add the end of the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to replace URL with your local REST API:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
    dataType:"jsonp",
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
  headers:{         
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHBWZXIiOiIwLjAuMCIsImV4cCI6NDcyNjM4OTEyMiwibG9jYWxlIjoiIiwibWFzdGVyVmVyIjoiIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiIiLCJwbGF0Zm9ybVZlciI6IiIsInVzZXJJZCI6IiJ9.QIZbmB5_9Xlap_gDhjETfMI6EAmR15yBtIQkWFWJkrg',
      
  },
  success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    console.log('data: ', data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When a server cannot understand a request,  its called 400 error. There are few reason for it. Maybe you have used a url with invalid token or cookie. Please make sure ur bearer token is valid.. Clear ur DNS cache, browser cache..i think its your bearer token.. Please make sure your bearer token is valid..