# dynamic choice field got 'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices'

Tags: python, django

I have 5 simple model class like this

```
# Province
class Provinsi(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=3, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

# City
class Kota(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=5, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Provinsi, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
# District
class Kecamatan(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Kota, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
# Vilages
class Desa(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=12, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Kecamatan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
# Locations
class Lokasi(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    provinsi = models.ForeignKey(Provinsi, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    kota = models.ForeignKey(Kota, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    kecamatan = models.ForeignKey(Kecamatan, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    desa = models.ForeignKey(Desa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

All first 4 class don't have admin page, it's "injected" using custom manage command

admin.py looks like

```
class LokasiAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = LokasiAdminForm
    change_form_template = 'lokasi_change.html'
     
admin.site.register(Lokasi, LokasiAdmin)
```

the template (lokasi_change.html) have some ajax call to update some choice fields based on change of other choice field.

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block after_field_sets %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // add listeners
    document.getElementById("id_provinsi").addEventListener("change", changedProvinsi);
    document.getElementById("id_kota").addEventListener("change", changedKota);
    document.getElementById("id_kecamatan").addEventListener("change", changedKecamatan);


    function changedProvinsi(){
        var myselect = document.querySelector('#id_provinsi');
        var myvalue = myselect.value;
        var baseurl = window.location.origin;
        var exturl = baseurl+'/setup/get_kota/'+myvalue;
        console.log('Ini ChangedProvinsi: '+ myvalue);
        console.log('ext url: '+ exturl);
        $("#id_kota option").remove();
        $('#id_kota').append(
                        $("<option></option>").attr("value","").text("----------")
                    );

        $("#id_kecamatan option").remove();
        $('#id_kecamatan').append(
                        $("<option></option>").attr("value","").text("----------")
                    );
        $("#id_desa option").remove();
        $('#id_desa').append(
                        $("<option></option>").attr("value","").text("----------")
                    );

        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/59029044/5901318
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:exturl,
            success: function(data, status, xhr){
                //di sini up date options nya 
                $.each(data, function(index, item){
                    $('#id_kota').append(
                        $("<option></option>").attr("value",item.value).text(item.label)
                    );
                });
                //$('#id_kota').val( $('select option:first').val() );
            }
        });
        //console.log('asu'+document.querySelector('#id_kota').querySelector('option')[0].value);
    };

    function changedKota(){
        var myselect = document.querySelector('#id_kota');
        var myvalue = myselect.value;
        var baseurl = window.location.origin;
        var exturl = baseurl+'/setup/get_kecamatan/'+myvalue

        console.log('Ini ChangedKota')
        $("#id_kecamatan option").remove();
        $('#id_kecamatan').append(
                        $("<option></option>").attr("value","").text("----------")
                    );
        $("#id_desa option").remove();
        $('#id_desa').append(
                        $("<option></option>").attr("value","").text("----------")
                    );
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:exturl,
            success: function(data, status, xhr){
                //di sini up date options nya 
                $.each(data, function(index, item){
                    $('#id_kecamatan').append(
                        $("<option></option>").attr("value",item.value).text(item.label)
                    );
                });
                //$('#id_kecamatan').val( $('select option:first').val() );
            }
        });
    };

    function changedKecamatan(){
        var myselect = document.querySelector('#id_kecamatan');
        var myvalue = myselect.value;
        var baseurl = window.location.origin;
        var exturl = baseurl+'/setup/get_desa/'+myvalue

        console.log('Ini ChangedKecamatan')
        $("#id_desa option").remove();
        $('#id_desa').append(
                        $("<option></option>").attr("value","").text("----------")
                    );
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:exturl,
            success: function(data, status, xhr){
                //di sini up date options nya 
                $.each(data, function(index, item){
                    $('#id_desa').append(
                        $("<option></option>").attr("value",item.value).text(item.label)
                    );
                });
                $('#id_desa').val( $('select option:first').val() );
            }
        });
    };

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

and here is LokasiAdminForm class in forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Lokasi, Provinsi, Kota, Kecamatan, Desa

class LokasiAdminForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            self.fields['kota'].queryset = self.instance.provinsi.kota_set.all()
        except Exception as e:
            self.fields['kota'].queryset = Kota.objects.none()

        try:
            self.fields['kecamatan'].queryset = self.instance.kota.kecamatan_set.all()
        except Exception as e:
            self.fields['kecamatan'].queryset = Kecamatan.objects.none()

        try:
            self.fields['desa'].queryset = self.instance.kecamatan.desa_set.all()
        except Exception as e:
            self.fields['desa'].queryset = Desa.objects.none()
```

the change view shows perfectly
(this one after I put some choices)

[image]

But when I click 'save', it shows error "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices" for that 3 dynamic choice fields (Kota, Kecamatan, Desa)

[image]

I Try to add 'clean' in forms.py, trying to update queryset of that 3 dynamic choice fields.

```
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()

        if self.cleaned_data['provinsi']:
            self.fields['kota'].queryset=self.cleaned_data['provinsi'].kota_set.all()

        if self.cleaned_data['kota']:
            self.fields['kecamatan'].queryset=self.cleaned_data['kota'].kecamatan_set.all()

        if self.cleaned_data['kecamatan']:
            self.fields['desa'].queryset=self.cleaned_data['kecamatan'].desa_set.all()
```

but looks like that last 3 dynamic choice field (kota, kecamatan, desa) is not in 'cleaned data'.
So I got error : KeyError: 'kota'

Only 'provinsi' that in 'cleaned_data'.

Kindly please tell me how to fix this